# How do I get lines between same pattern using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string "s" as follows

> s="abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc"

I want to grep the strings which occurs in between "abc". In this case the output should be:

> 123, fndf, 1234drf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [positive lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion like below.

```
>>> import re
>>> s="abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=abc).*?(?=abc)', s)
['123', 'fndf', '1234drf']
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=abc)` Positive Lookbehind which asserts that the string preceds the match must be `abc`
- `.*?` Non-greedy match of zero or more chracaters.
- `(?=abc)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the string follows the match must be `abc`

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is an assignment where you *must* use regex you should use vikramls's `split()`-based solution: it's over three times as fast as Avinash Raj's regex-based solution, and that's not including the time to import the `re` module.

Here are some timings done on a 2GHz Pentium 4, using Python 2.6.6.

`$ timeit.py -n 100000 -s "import re;p=re.compile(r'(?<=abc).*?(?=abc)');s='abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc'" "p.findall(s)"`

100000 loops, best of 3: 6.32 usec per loop

`$ timeit.py -n 100000 -s "p='abc';s='abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc'" "s.split(p)"`

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 usec per loop

And a variation of the above that discards the initial & final members of the list is slightly slower, but still better than twice as fast as the regex.

`$ timeit.py -n 100000 -s "p='abc';s='abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc'" "s.split(p)[1:-1]"`

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.49 usec per loop

And for completeness, here's vks's regex. The `"'!'"` stuff is to prevent the `!` from invoking bash history expansion. (Alternatively, you can use `set +o histexpand` to turn history expansion off and `set -o histexpand` to turn it back on).

`$ timeit.py -n 100000 -s "import re;p=re.compile(r'(?<=abc)((?:(?"'!'"abc).)+)abc');s='abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc'" "p.findall(s)"`

100000 loops, best of 3: 6.67 usec per loop

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=abc)((?:(?!abc).)+)abc
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/17

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=abc)((?:(?!abc).)+)abc')
test_str = u"abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not using regex:

```
s= "abc123abcfndfabc1234drfabc"
print ', '.join((w for w in s.split('abc') if w))
```

#### Output:

```
123, fndf, 1234drf
```