# How to replace consecutive spaces in a string in python

Tags: python

I have a awfully formatted data file with data structure as below:

```
" id1    id2             id3         id4"
"  id1    id2            id3         id4"
" id1     id2             id3         id4"
```

I should retrieve id2 and id4 in each line, but number of spaces in each line between ids differs. Is there a way i could replace all consecutive spaces in each line with some character like '/t' so i could retrieve second and fourth item in each line?!
I appreciate any help.

Comment: A army of programer helped you :)

Comment: @Hackaholic: And amazingly no downvotes (so far) for lack of code in the question. :)

Comment: As you can see from the answers below there's no need to clean up the formatting, since `split()` happily copes with variable numbers of spaces, and it's easy to write regexes that handle them too. But I guess it would be more efficient to reformat the file if you need to access it often. Note that the split-based solutions will be 2 or 3 times faster than the regex-based ones. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27099374/4014959) I posted yesterday that contains timing data comparing regex with split in a somewhat similar scenario.

Comment: Thanks everyone for not giving me a downvotes, i had some long code in mind but just putting them here would have been nonsense, I have used split() method hundreds of times, but i never knew leaving it without any argument results this way!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do a `.split()` which automatically splits on any number of whitespace characters and ignores leading and trailing whitespace:

```
>>> s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
>>> items = s.split()
>>> items
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

That way, you can access `items[1]` and `items[3]` directly. If you want to rebuild them into a tab-separated string, use `.join()`:

```
>>> "\t".join(items)
'id1\tid2\tid3\tid4'
```

Answer (score 3):

using re.sub

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
>>> re.sub('\s+',' ',s.strip())
'id1 id2 id3 id4'
```

you can use split and slicing:

```
>>> s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
>>> s.split()[1::2]
['id2', 'id4']
```

using re.findall:

```
>>> s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
>>> re.findall('id[24]',s)
['id2', 'id4']
```

Comment: Nice use of slicing. And I reckon you deserve a point for using `split()` and not just showing regex-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split to get elements:

```
s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
frst,sec,th,frth = s.split()
print(sec,frth)
id2 id4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = " id1    id2             id3         id4"
>>> s.split()
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
>>> '\t'.join(s.split())
'id1\tid2\tid3\tid4'
>>> print '\t'.join(s.split())
id1     id2     id3     id4
```

To extract `id2` and `id4` use indexing with `str.split`

```
>>> a, b = s.split()[1], s.split()[3]
>>> a, b
('id2', 'id4')
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to compare the timing of your hybrid indexing and unpacking approach compared to Paddy's pure unpacking-based answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes my approach(723 ns per loop) is slow than Padraic Cunningham solution( 511 ns per loop),. but i store less variable too. but thanks for your consideration.

Comment: And thankyou for taking the trouble to do the timing. I suspected your way would be slower, but I wasn't sure. And I guess the actual relative speed would vary across implementations.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes implementation issues, if you hvae many variables then my solution can be preffered because of less memory space, but here it's slightly slow.

Comment: True, but I actually meant that the different implementations of Python itself may vary in the relative speed that they handle unpacking vs indexing. Sorry for not being more clear in my previous comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes very True.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub(' +', ' ', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant way to do it, but easy to understand. This function replaces consecutive spaces with a single space.

```
def remove_extra_spaces(s):
    s_res = ""
    flip = False
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ':
            # first one is ok, next ones not
            if not flip:
                s_res += c
            flip = True
        else:
            flip = False
            s_res += c

    return s_res
```